# The cause of the error "List matching query does not exist."

Tags: python, html, sql, django, sqlite

I'm writing a Django auction program, and in the last levels of the program, when I wrote the code to select the winner of the auction and created the corresponding table with sqlite, I encountered this error. After this bug, no products will be displayed on the main page and product information cannot be seen.
What is the cause of this error?

I changed the names of the columns of the table, but it had no effect, and the rest of the code was working before creating this table.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\N\Desktop\New folder\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 72, in item_detail
    bid_desc = List.objects.get(pk = bidid, active_bool = True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\N\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    ^

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /auctions/1
Exception Value: List matching query does not exist.
```

These codes are related to the winning section in the display and template.

```
# item detail page
def item_detail(request, bidid):
    bid_desc = List.objects.get(pk = bidid, active_bool = True)
    nowbids = Bidmodel.objects.filter(listb_id = bidid)
    
    return render(request, "auctions/item_detail.html",{
        "list": bid_desc,
        "comments" : Comments.objects.filter(listc_id = bidid),
        "now_bid": minbid(bid_desc.first_bid, nowbids),
})

# winner
def winner(request):
    bid_id = request.GET["listid"]
    nowbids = Bidmodel.objects.filter(listb_id = bid_id)
    biddesc = List.objects.get(pk = bid_id, active_bool = True)
    maxbid = minbid(biddesc.first_bid, nowbids)

    try:
        winner_who = Bidmodel.objects.get(bid = maxbid, listb_id = bid_id)
        winner_list = List.objects.get(id = bid_id)
        win = Winner(win_list = winner_list, user = winner_who.user)
        winners_name = winner_who.user
    
    except:
        winner_list = List.objects.get(first_bid = maxbid, id = bid_id)
        win = Winner(win_list = winner_list, user = winner_list.user)
        winners_name = winner_list.user

    biddesc.active_bool = False
    biddesc.save()
    win.save()
    messages.success(request, f"{winners_name} won {win.win_list.title}.")
    return redirect("index")



# check winner
def winner_check(request):
    try:
        yourwin = Winner.objects.filter(user = request.user.username)
    except:
        yourwin = None

    return render(request, "auctions/winner_check.html",{
        "user_winlist" : yourwin,
    })



{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Your Winnings</h2>
    <div>
        {% for list in user_winlist %}
            <div>
                <a>{{list.bid_win_list.title}}</a>
                <a>{{list.bid_win_list.category}}</a>
                <img src="{{ list.bid_win_list.image_url }}">
                <p>{{ list.bid_win_list.descRIPTION }}</p>
                <div>This bid was listed by <a>{{ list.bid_win_list.user }}</a>.</div>
            </div>  
        {% endfor %}
    </div>


CREATE TABLE auctions_winner(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
user TEXT,
win_list_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Without the code, the best guess I have is that `/auctions/1` is a GET request for a record in the auctions table with id=1, and no such record exists.

Comment: @MichaelRuth   Thank you very much for your reply

Before the creation of the table, /auctions/1 displayed the product specifications, but now it is not displayed.
The volume of the code is relatively high, and for a better understanding, it is necessary to send the entire program, which is not possible... However, in the editing of the question that I will publish in the next few minutes, I will also write the codes related to the winning part of the auction.

Comment: The error comes from a line in `item_detail` view, which is not shown in the question currently. Do you definitely have a List with `active_bool = True` in the database? Is the value of `bidid` correct?

Comment: @Anentropic
 I have 'active_bool = True' in this function, if I delete it, it displays the information, however, it is not possible to close the auction and determine the winner, and it gives the same error again for the function I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Anentropic I added the function you mentioned to the description   And thank you for your reply.

Comment: `List.objects.get(pk = bidid, active_bool = True)` means get the row from the List db table that has primary key id equal to `bidid` AND `active_bool` field is True. The error is saying that no such record exists in the db. You say if you remove `active_bool = True` from the query then you can get a response, so it sounds like there is a row where `pk = bidid` but it has `active_bool = False`.

Comment: @Anentropic  Yesss...I understood and I was able to fix it to some extent. Thank you for your guidance and help....